# Problemas con setCustomValidity (setCustomValidity is not a function)

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy realizando una validación en cliente de los campos de un formulario. A la hora de realizar la validación en JavaScript, tengo problemas con setCustomValidity, ya que si le doy a inspeccionar en la página me salta el error descrito en el título: Uncaught TypeError: longitud.setCustomValidity is not a function. El código de la función es el siguiente.

```js
function longitudValidation(){
 var longitud = document.getElementById("longitudVarilla");
 var l = longitud.value;
 if(l < 0 || l > 2000){
  var error = "La longitud de la varilla debe ser un número comprendido entre 0 y 2000";
} else if(l == ""){
 var error = "Por favor, introduzca la longitud de la varilla";
} else {
 var error = "";
}
longitud.setCustomValidity(error);
return error;
}
```

El campo longitud está definido en el formulario por la etiqueta select, y es de tipo numérico, no sé si eso puede estar dando problemas. A la hora de utilizar la función para validar, utilizo el atributo onchange. Además, en la etiqueta form, utilizo el atributo onsubmit. Adjunto además el código de esas 2 etiquetas.

```html
<form id="añadirVarilla" method="get" action="validacion_alta_varilla.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<!--Aquí irían una serie de inputs y selects antes de la longitud -->
<label id="longitudVarilla">Longitud(en milímetros): </label>
<input id="longitudVarilla" type="number" name="longitudVarilla" max="2000" min="0" oninput="longitudValidation();" required/>
```

No sé cuál puede ser el problema. He pensado que el problema puede estar en que el setCustomValidity no sirve para campos numéricos, pero aparte de eso no tengo ni idea.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he solucionado. Al parecer, en la etiqueta del formulario label, tenía puesto label id, en lugar de label for, y eso me estaba causando ciertos conflictos.